# Disadvantages of Qt

Tags: qt

I'm beginner in qt. I think it's useful but there is some thing wrong. I think it's not the number one developer's choice. Why developers don't like using Qt?
And what is the best replacement for Qt?

Comment: What type of applications are you trying to create? (Desktop, web, mobile, ...) What operating systems are you targeting? (Windows, Mac OS X, Ubuntu, ...) That information would help us determine a better fit for your needs.

Comment: Sorry, in this form, this question isn't welcome on *any* of the StackExchange websites.  If you wish to discuss the advantages and disadvantages of Qt, go to programmers.stackexchange.com.  And, please, consult their faq to ensure you don't end up getting closed there.

Answer (score 13):

When you use Qt you get spoiled by the extensive documentation so when you switch to another toolkit you'll be miserable.

This is my only complaint with the Qt.

Comment: Don't forget the increased productivity in UI design and implementation such that when you switch to another toolkit you have to work harder to achieve the same results ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing purely on Windows then C# may give you easier links into Windows technologies, it's also a simpler language than C++ - although they are working on that.

For C++ there isn't really a good alternative toolkit.
On Windows, MFC is a bit long in the tooth, managed c++ (or whatever it's called this week) together with .Net is a pain^2.
On Linux, Gnome requires you to write c in c++ while thinking in objective c.

Comment: +1 for description of writing for Gnome

Answer (score -2):

depends on language but most developers that i know use visual studio, especially for c++ etc

Comment: Most Qt developers on Windows use VS

Comment: This is not a downside of Qt. You can use Qt with VS on windows perfectly. Update your answer and i'll take my -1 back.